# MySQL search match part of word

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For a small and simple search tool on my site I use MySQL's MATCH AGAINST to find the most relevant rows based on a search term. Now I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('".$term."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If I, for instance, search for 'sys' the query gives me results with words like system or systems. The problem that I'm having and the thing I would like to achieve is that when the search term is 'systems' I only get results with the exact word 'systems', where I would like to get results with the word 'system' as well.

I already checked the Docs but I can't seem to find a solution. Did someone run into this before?

Comment: This is not possible. Think about it. With this: `'".$term."*` you defined, that if the search is started with `'systems*'` then it will show you every records, what started with `systems`, and `'systemstools'`, etc... How to mysql should figure out, that you need `'system'` if you give the search term with `s` at the end?

Comment: I understand. But is there way how this can be done?

Comment: Cut the last s, or last letter, or use the first 3 word, I don't know, what is your logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

What you are asking for is usually implemented in one of two ways in a full text search engine.  The more common method is a list of synonyms for terms.  These would allow you say that "system" and "systems" are the same thing.

As far as I know, MySQL does not support synonym lists.  You can implement them yourself, in a cumbersome manner, by pre-processing the data or queries to substitute synonym values.

The second approach is called stemming.  This transforms words into their "root" form, so "systems" would be recognized as the plural of "system" and the two would match.  Stemming can be applied only in the query.  Or, for the truly ambitious, it can be applied on the document storage side as well.  The problem there is ambiguity.  English (and other languages) are filled with exceptions where stemming doesn't make sense.